# Failed building wheel, when I am trying to install with pip

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip

When I am trying to find, install numpy, matplotlib and scipy. I am unable to install via pip packages. It is showing the following error
[image]

Is there any other packages to display plotting values?

Comment: Please see the image description for the error

Comment: Use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to make your life easy on Windows.

Comment: Given you image is just a stack trace, please just post the text in a code block

Comment: Will try Burhan Khalid....

Comment: I added image to body but please edit in your traceback as code block like Andrew said.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you could use binary packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

You could download wheels and then install them with `pip`, e.g. for `numpy`:

```
pip install numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

**EDIT**

from that site with packages for numpy:

> Numpy+MKL includes required DLLs in the numpy.core directory.
>   The vanilla builds are less tested and not compatible with many other binaries on this page.

So try to install mkl version.

Comment: Anton..this particular pip install command didn't work out. I have wheel already downloaded. You have given a link, with pip's listed. Will that packages have size of 116 MB?

Comment: I have tried the same, with another package called plotly,(in the process of downloading ). even this is showing only a GUI window but not graphs. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: I couldn't `plotly` packages there, may be you mean `matplotlib`? Do you have all dependencies satisfied?

Comment: No, it is still showing the same error. I tried to download the mkl version and tried to run the program, but it is still showing the wheel error. I am unable to understand this error.

Comment: So then try to install anaconda. It'll easy for you to do